# Portable mining device

Tags: mining-hardware

What's a good portable (as carrying it in my shoulder together with my laptop) mining device? Besides the laptop, how could I add more power to mining Monero?

Is any device small enough to be carried every day and worth its cost?

Answer (score 1):

Actually, there is no device that is so small that you could carry it with you like a laptop.

You could build your own desktop computer with a small case and a really good processor (that's what is important for mining Monero) but it would most probably still be bigger then a laptop.

Answer (score 0):

You could carry a battery pack and Raspberry Pi's.  They should mine ~10H/s.  Maybe an Odroid could push it a little further, but that is the most portable thing I can imagine.